# Java data grid control

Tags: java, database, user-interface, grid

Are there any third party enterprisey data grid controls out there, alla JIDE Data Grid? Is there a website like torry.net that lists third party java controls? Google doesn't turn up much for and I thought there would be a lot of both considering how popular java seems to be.

TIA

Answer (score 2):

Most Java frameworks offer that kind of component or widget. You can look into SWT (from eclipse), they is very good stuff in there: http://www.eclipse.org/swt/. You could also look into Jambi (Qt in Java) from http://trolltech.com/products/appdev/programming-language-support. Now, if your into web apps, there are infinite options.

Comment: Unfortunately Qt Jambi has been discontinued.

Answer (score 0):

I usually look on component sales sites like
http://www.componentsource.com/features/grids/java-components/index.html

Jonathan Wax
jwaxster@gmail.com